# IDE: [error] Threw an exception: missing ; before statement

Tags: selenium, javascript, selenium-ide

I keep getting errors with my storeEval script. In IDE the log keeps giving me "[error] Threw an exception: missing ; before statement". I don't know what to do because I have tried putting a similar command in this test from another test that works and it'll fail as well.

`<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>id=poCostForRow0</td>
    <td>EclipseCost</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>rollup</td>
    <td>completeOrder</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>rollup</td>
    <td>loginApollo</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=projectNameForRow0</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>id=poCostForItem0ForPO0</td>
    <td>ApolloCost</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript { storedVars[&quot;EclipseCost&quot;].substring(9,16);}</td>
    <td>y</td>
</tr>`

Answer (score 1):

try to change THIS

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript { storedVars[&quot;EclipseCost&quot;].substring(9,16);}</td>
    <td>y</td>
</tr>
```

for THIS

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['EclipseCost'].substring(9,16)</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
```

(works for me)

You don't have to use `javascript {}` in `storeEval` which is designed for single statement. The error was probably caused by use of storeEval itself. If you switch `storeEval` for `storeExpression`, it would work, cause is designed for javascript processing.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `javascript`**{**`...`**}** try to use `javascript`**(**`...`**)**    *(round brackets)*.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: this is surely not a good answer